# How, the first (ever) transaction sender, earned his balance?

Tags: transactions, genesis

I've recentaly started learning about blockchain, dapps and Ethereum.

I've readed on the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (and some questions on Stack Exachange) that, differently from Bitcoin, in Ethereum the "genesis block" is hardcored and not mined: this involves that no one got the reward associtated with it. So, my question is: how, in the first ever transaction on the Ethereum network, does the sender earned his funds to sustain his transaction? Since no value wasn't currency circulated yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ethereum the genesis block is special. The contributors balances were initialized directly in the Ethereum World State, so it didn't costs any fees.